# Counting lists?

Tags: mustache

Let's take this snippet:

```
{{#repos}}
<b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repos}}
```

How can I count the number of items in `repos`?

Answer (score 4):

One way is to add the logic to the JSON itself as a function on `this`:

```
var tmpl = "{{#repos}}<b>{{name}}</b>{{/repos}}({{count}})";

var json = {
    repos: [{ name: "Tom"}, { name: "Dick"}, { name: "Harry"}],
    count: function() { return this.repos.length; }
};
alert(Mustache.to_html(tmpl, json));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QBzuk/

Answer (score 3):

At least for me, I was able to use the ".length" function directly like this: (tested with Mustache v 0.8.1)

```
var tmpl = "{{#repos}}<b>{{name}}</b>{{/repos}} ({{repos.length}})";
var json = {
    repos: [{ name: "Tom"}, { name: "Dick"}, { name: "Harry"}]
};
alert(Mustache.to_html(tmpl, json));
```

Alerts out "`<b>Tom</b><b>Dick</b><b>Harry</b> (3)`"